# for the instance of Alloy analyzer

Tags: alloy

I want to transfer the instance of the alloy analyzer.in other words

[image]

How to output txt format as a file?

Because I want to develop a software that calls this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instances can be saved as XML files both using the Alloy analyzer GUI and the Alloy API.

If you are interested in making that XML representation of your Alloy instance more human readable, you can specify a transformation (in xslt for example), to format the data as you see fit.

Have fun :+)